# ForEach-Object -Parallel How to use it

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I'm starting to use `ForEach-Object -Parallel` with **PowerShell 7**. I'm testing following code:

```
$MyArr = @()
$MyArr = (
    ('v1ne','rgNE'),`
    ('v1we','rgWE')
)

$MyArr | ForEach-Object -Parallel  { 
    Start-AzVM -Name $MyArr[0]  -ResourceGroupName $MyArr[1]
} -ThrottleLimit 10
```

To start up some virtual machine on azure in different Resource Groups. My idea is to get variable from array or from Azure automation variables. But I don't know how to pass different Resource Group Names in `ForEach-Object -Parallel`.

Any help is really appreciate.

Comment: Just like when using `ForEach-Object` _without_ `-Parallel`, the current input item will be bound to `$_`, so: `Start-AzVM -Name $_[0]  -ResourceGroupName $_[1]`

Comment: hi @MathiasR.Jessen , it works. 

If i want parameters into some variable? Something like:

$vmWE = 'vm1;vm2'
$rgWE = 'rgWE'
$vmNE = 'vm1;vm2'
$rgNE = 'rgWE'
**
There is a way to do that?

Comment: Your safest bet for this example would be an array of hashtables, so you can use splatting like `Start-AzVM @_`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) explained in comments, when using [`ForEach-Object -Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-11--run-slow-script-in-parallel-batches), you would need to use [`$_` (also known as `$PSItem`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#_) to reference **the current object from pipeline** (same applies for `ForEach-Object`). If you want to reference a variable that is not coming from pipeline you would use the `$using:` keyworkd.

Example:

```
$notFromPipeline = 'Hello'

0..5 | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    "$using:notFromPipeline $_"
}
```

As for, how you could approach your script, I think *splatting with `$_`* seems fit for this, suppose you had a CSV with the **VM Names** and their corresponding **Resource Groups**, something like:

- **VMs.csv**

```
Name,ResourceGroupName
v1ne,rgNE
v1we,rgwE
```

You could do something like this, **note**, below example is using a function (`TestSplat`) just to show you how the parameters are bound using [*splatting with a hash table*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.2#splatting-with-hash-tables), in your case, you would replace this function for `Start-AzVM`.

First you can create an array of *hash tables* like this:

```
$myParams = Import-Csv ./VMs.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $z = @{}
    foreach($prop in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
        $z[$prop.Name] = $prop.Value
    }
    $z
}
```

`$myParams` would be something like this:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Name                           v1ne
ResourceGroupName              rgNE
Name                           v1we
ResourceGroupName              rgwE
```

The column names of your CSV **must match with the Parameter Names of `Start-VM` (`Name` and `ResourceGroupName`)**.

Now you can iterate over `$myParams` using `ForEach-Object -Parallel`:

```
$myParams | ForEach-Object -Parallel  {
    function TestSplat {
        param($Name, $ResourceGroupName)
        Write-Host "Name: $Name - ResourceGroup: $ResourceGroupName"
    }

    TestSplat @_
} -ThrottleLimit 10
```

Which should result in:

```
Name: v1ne - ResourceGroup: rgNE
Name: v1we - ResourceGroup: rgwE
```

Comment: It is worth mentioneing that this would only work on Powershell 7.0 + , in Powershell 5.0 the parallel loop is possible throughout a `workflow` , and is not supported otherwise.

Comment: @VasilNikolov OP has already stated that this question is meant for PowerShell 7+, on the other hand, `workflow` is meant for long-running tasks not for this specific question. In Windows PowerShell, for truly multi-threading you would be using the ThreadJob module from Microsoft or Runspaces.

Comment: Hi thanks, i had to rollback to 5.1 because with 7.1 webhook didn't working